# Bootstrap tooltip dont work on mouse over when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I cant figure out how to keep tooltip hover functionality when click on element that shows tooltip on hover. So basically i want to hide tooltip every time cursor leaves element, no matter if its clicked or not.

Here's example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <button type = " button" class = " btn btn-default" data-toggle = "tooltip" 
                data-placement = "right" title = "Tooltip on right">Tooltip</button>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
                    });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to say when mouse leave lose the focus of the active element see code below:

```
$('#btn').on({
  mouseleave: function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }
});
```

Of course I've just added the id to the button to make it easier to test.